# Алгоритм группировки слов, начинающихся с одинаковой буквы

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть массив со словами, отсортированными по алфавиту. К примеру:

```
String[] mass = { "арбуз", "биржа", "бокс", "болт", "сапог", "сарай" };
```

Нужно получить из этого массива `HashMap`:

```
[б=[биржа, бокс, болт], c=[caпог, сарай]]
```

Как должен строиться алгоритм?

Comment: Самое интересное, что если бы мы добавляли слова в HashMap, то нужно было бы получить по сути внутреннее представление этой HashMap. Единственное, что нужно для слов переопределить hashCode(), который бы учитывал только первую букву. Потом пройтись итератором и получить (несортированный) список.

Answer (score 4):

Если говорить конкретно про алгоритм решения, то скорее всего самый оптимальный будет следующий:

1. создаем пустой объект HashMap с ключем в виде строки (или символа) и значением в виде списка строк
2. обходим элементы массива и выполняем следующее:

   - получаем первую букву из строки для использования в качестве ключа
   - получаем из HashMap список по ключу (если его ещё нет - создаем и добавляем в HashMap)
   - добавляем в полученный список исходный элемент массива (строку)

В общем случае на Java такой алгоритм будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Map<Character, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (String word : mass) {
    Character key = word.charAt(0);
    List<String> list = map.get(key);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        map.put(key, list);
    }
    list.add(word);
}
```

Довольно просто данную задачу можно решить через Stream API:

```
String[] mass = {"арбуз", "биржа", "бокс", "болт", "сапог", "сарай" };

Map<Character, List<String>> result = Arrays.stream(mass)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.charAt(0), Collectors.toList()));

result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));

// Out:
//   а -> [арбуз]
//   с -> [сапог, сарай]
//   б -> [биржа, бокс, болт]
```

Если конечный вывод нужно отсортировать по ключам - можно использовать следующее:

```
result.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
    .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " -> " + entry.getValue()));

// Out:
// а -> [арбуз]
// б -> [биржа, бокс, болт]
// с -> [сапог, сарай]
```

Comment: Круто, даже очень круто. Но пока сложно понять что происходит. Если вдруг есть инфа где можно почитать про Stream api для чайников, не могли бы поделится.

Comment: @АнатолийФерисов [одна статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/270383/), [другая](https://habrahabr.ru/post/302628/), ну и далее по Гуглу на запрос "java stream api", если статей не хватит (я их не читал, так что не знаю насколько они подробны).  И обратите внимание на [эту страницу](http://tsya.ru/mnemonic.html).